# Karate Cucumber Runner throws "No Such Method"

Tags: cucumber, karate

**I'm getting below exception after upgrading Cucumber and Karate versions.**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>   cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions.cucumberFeatures(Lcucumber/runtime/io/ResourceLoader;)Ljava/util/List;
>     at
>   com.intuit.karate.cucumber.CucumberRunner.(CucumberRunner.java:70)
>     at
>   com.intuit.karate.testng.KarateRunner.setUpClass(KarateRunner.java:32)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:458)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:142)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:168)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

**Here is my launcher/runner:**

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features/PatientMS.feature", plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-report/jsonfiles", "json:target/cucumber-report/jsonfiles/PatientMS.json" })
public class PatientMSLauncher extends KarateRunner {

}
```

**Karate & Cucumber dependencies:**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-jvm -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-apache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
            <artifactId>karate-testng</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

I tried running by JUnit but no luck!|
How can I handle this issue?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to add glue attribute in your testrunner calss

Comment: I think it must work without glue attribute,  Peter did a really great job and covered most of REST methods by Karate.
If we have pure Karate project with no additional definitions glue will be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing Karate and possibly Cucumber 3 in your pom.xml - which is not supported.

If you are still stuck, please go through this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Hi Peter,
thanks for your response, how can I find supported cucumber version by Karate? In case we need to check compatibility.

Comment: Karate brings a modified Cucumber version along with it. teams typically just use the karate dependency and nothing else. if you add more stuff to the `pom.xml` you are on your own.